entropy of weighted sampling without replacement
Let us have $k$ elements of weights $w_1,…,w_k$.
We sample elements with weights without replacement.
At the first, the probability of element $i$ to be sampled is $w_i / \sum_{l=1}^k w_l$.
Then, the probability of element $j$ to be sampled second is $w_j / \sum_{l=1,l!=i}^k w_l$.
In this manner, We sample until we pull all the $k$ elements.
The probability of a sequence $s=(s_1, s_2, ..., s_k)$ would be $p(s) = \Pi_{j=1}^k [w_j / \sum_{l=j}^k w_l]$. ($w_i$ for $s_i$ for simplicity).
The entropy $H(s)$ is $\sum_{s \in S}- p(s)\text{log}p(s)$. ($S$ is a set of all permutations.)
Is there any closed form of approximation for this entropy?
Thanks in advance!!
